# swift 3 loop error (taking variable and adding it by itself)

Tags: swift, loops, addition

My code does not work right now. I am trying to take names and add it by itself in the loop but the complier is giving me a error message and the code is not being printed.

```
let names = [Double(2),3,8] as [Any]
let count = names.count
for i in 0..<count {
    print((names[i]) + names[i])
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What's the point of the `as [Any]`?

Comment: Well `names` is an `[Any]`, so the elements could be, well, *anything*. You cannot add together arbitrary things – what if `names[i]` was a `Bool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `as [Any]` makes no sense. You can't add two objects of type `Any` which is probably what your error is about.

Simply drop it and your code works.

```
let names = [Double(2),3,8]
let count = names.count
for i in 0..<count {
    print(names[i] + names[i])
}
```

Output:

> 4.0
>   6.0
>   16.0

Better yet:

```
let names = [Double(2),3,8]
for num in names {
    print(num + num)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Any` doesn't have `+` operator.

This will give you the result you expected.

If you want to add 2 values and print the result, you need to cast `Any` to calculatable like `Double`

```
let names = [Double(2),3,8] as [Any]
let count = names.count
for i in 0..<count {
    if let value = names[i] as? Double {
        print(value + value)
    }
}
```